# How can I create a shortcut to a particular Google keep label?

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts

I would like to create a shortcut to my Google keep items labeled "shopping". How can I do this?

Comment: That would be great. Of course, what I *really* want is a widget that opens a to-do list and lets me add an item via voice.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. The only way is to add Google Keep widget on your home screen.
Then you can list all your labels and access the very fast.

Comment: Well that's suboptimal.

Comment: I know, I was looking for that solution too, but Google Keep doesn't  have that feature.

Comment: I'm leaving Google feedback on this. I hope they will add this feature soon.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently that is not possible with Google Keep. You can only have a widget to the label list.
I assume you need to access a list/note very frequently. To resolve that let you most used note be on the top, that's how I manage.

Comment: How do you get a widget to the label list?

Comment: Just like any other widget on the Home Screen. Keep has two widgets of it's own. Check that on your device's home screen;varies from oem to oem.